# IIS application runs without bindings with https url address

Tags: iis, dns

I'm not a server admin or expert but as far as I know if you want your application run with https protocol you have to define the https binding of the site in IIS with the same address as DNS record. But lately I saw an IIS server on one of our customer that they didn't define the https binding and just had a http binding with different port like 82. I wonder how users can navigate to this application with a url something like https://somesite.com and how the application runs without defined bindings, how it can be?

If I want to make same thing on my applications, how can I do that?

Comment: This can be achieved by configuring a reverse proxy. In this scenario, the proxy handles the HTTPS communication and forwards the requests to the IIS server as HTTP.